# Unable to solve flask_app import and flask_mail issue in Pythonanywhere

Tags: python

I am trying to deploy my web application on PythonAnywhere from my local pc .I have tried everything and still getting the same error:

1. ERROR 1:
   Error running WSGI application:
   ModuleNotFoundError : No module named "flask_app"
   File "/var/www/astrid20_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in 
   from flask_app import app as application  #noqa

(The name of my application is :web.py. I also made changes in WSGI link(under code section) as:
from web import app as application.
My file path is also correct.)

2. ERROR 2:
   Error running WSGI application
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mail'
   File "/var/www/astrid20_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in 
   from web import app as application  #noqa

File "/home/Astrid20/mysite/web.py", line 2, in 
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

I used flask_mail function in my code and uploaded the code file.
I have no idea what I did wrong, I am stuck. Could anyone please help?!

Comment: Welcome to SO in order to ask questions you should review the following https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
                                                                              
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have flask_mail installed for the python version you use in your web app? There are multiple versions of python on PythonAnywhere and each of them has its own set of packages. You may be also running your web app in the virtual environment.